# MySQL not updating repetitive query

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

I have a python program (using PyMySQL) connected to my MySQL database.
In my program, I have a loop that checks the length of one of my tables.

```
sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM resourciter.views"
sqlCursor.execute(sql)
viewPointCount = sqlCursor.fetchone()[0]
print("(%s data points)" % str(viewPointCount))
```

However, every time this runs, it returns the same value even though I know it should be changing

Eg.

```
(46 data points)
(46 data points)
(46 data points)
(46 data points)
...
```

I tried closing and re-opening the sql connection upon every loop and suddenly it worked correctly

Eg.

```
(46 data points)
(47 data points)
(48 data points)
(49 data points)
...
```

Obviously this is very bad practice, and I'm sure it can work without closing and re-opening the connection.

Is there some sort of cache or something in the sqlCursor I need to clear?

Answer (score 1):

In versions of MySQL prior to 8, you can do

```
 SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE COUNT(*) FROM table
```

to get an uncached result from the query.

It's not necessary in version 8 and beyond; the query-cache capability was removed.

Comment: I noticed when trying to use the "SQL_NO_CACHE" command, it kept telling me it was depreciated and not functional anymore.

Comment: Finally got it to work. All it took was just a connection.commit() command every time (I had autocommit turned off). Not sure if this is the most efficient fix, but it worked.